# How to execute javascript inside a script tag returned by an ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm sending a jquery get request like so:

```
$.get($(this).attr("href"), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
```

The response I expect to receive will be wrapped in script tags.

I understand the browser doesn't execute the response unless its returned without the script tags. Normally I would remove the tags from the response but in this situation I don't have access to the code running on the remote machine so cannot strip out the tags at the source.

Is there a way I can strip out the script tags from the response client side and execute the javascript?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
$.get($(this).attr("href"), $(this).serialize(), function(data){
   var script = $(data).text();
   eval(script);
});
```

Comment: I would recommend adding var before script, to prevent it from being global.

Comment: I'd like this in vanilla JS please...?

Answer (score 6):

Or:

```
var myScript = new Function($('script#myscript',responseText).text());
myScript();
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question right, this should suffice to get the text out of the script tags:

> `$(response).text()`

Answer (score 1):

Would this help you: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript ?

Comment: That would work if the returned data was not wrapped in <script> tags

Answer (score 1):

Jose Basilio's answer is okay, but I recommend replacing *eval* with jQuery's *globalEval* function...

```
$.get($(this).attr("href"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
   script = $(data).text();
   $.globalEval(script);
});
```

*globalEval* is the function that would normally be called when you call an ajax method with a return type of *script*.

This from the API documentation...

> This method behaves differently from using a normal JavaScript eval()
>   in that it's executed within the global context (which is important
>   for loading external scripts dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

Say our response is in the 'response' var:

```
script = response.replace(/<script>(.*)<\/script>/, "$1"); // Remove tags
eval(script); // Execute javascript
```

Comment: If one were to use this solution, though, you'd probably have to complicate the regex a bit to allow for any attributes in the script tags, and probably anchor said regex to the beginning and end of the string.  For example (totally untested): /^<script[^>]+>(.*)<\/script>$/

Answer (score 0):

I did this slightly differently, and used php land to make it easier. (I don't like using eval, nor do I like huge conspicuous rewrites).

I placed all my jquery in a php string like so (there was a LOT more JavaScript in real life)

```
    $out .= "       $('#save_now').button(); \n";
    $out .= "       $('#save_now').click( function() {\n";
    $out .= "          return false;\n";
    $out .= "       }); \n";
```

then also in php land

```
    echo "<script>\n";
    echo "  function onOpen(){ \n";
    echo $out;
    echo "  } \n";
    echo "</script>\n";
```

then in the jQuery $.ajax call I do this

```
   $.ajax({
           url: geturl,
           type: 'post',
           data: getparams,
           success: function(data) {
               mydiv.html(data);  
               onOpen();  
           }, 
           cache: false
      });
```

as you can see you don't nee the php land thing, it's just in my code base I did sort of need to do it. the trick is to do away with `$(document).ready(function(){});` and roll your own