# how to run javascript within a ajax called file?

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
$.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      context: document.body,
      success: function(){
        $(this).addClass("done");
      }
    });
```

How do I run javascript  within  test.html  and make it work ?

Thanks
Abhinab

Comment: It doesn't make much sense the example, but apart from that, use `success : function (response)`, being `response` the returned html, so that you can manipulate it.

Comment: Similar to [How to execute javascript inside a script tag returned by an ajax response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978101/how-to-execute-javascript-inside-a-script-tag-returned-by-an-ajax-response)

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to execute javascript in test.html _before_ it is sent from the server to the browser? If so, the answer is easy. You can't.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really work like that. Javascript in a page is interpreted by the browser when the page is loaded. In this case you aren't loading a page in the browser, you're just getting the page in your ajax response. That response HTML may have <script> elements in them, but nothing is going to do anything with it.

I hesitate to even say this, but you *could* parse the response in your success function to find all of the script elements, then add whatever you're looking for to your own page's DOM. That should cause the script to be fetched and evaluated. I hesitate to mention it because it smells *really* bad. If any of my developers did this we'd be having a tough conversation. ;-)

It might help to elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish, as there might be a more elegant way to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 0):

```
function call_recursive(){
    var pages ["test1.html", "test2.html", "test3.html" ];

    while(pages.length() > 0){
        page = pages.pop();           
        $.ajax({
            url: page,
            context: document.body,
            success: function(){
                $("div#logger").append("<p>" + page " loded </p>");
            },
            error: function(){
                $("div#logger").append("<p class'error'>" + page " is not loded </p>");
            },
        });
    }
}
```

just execute **call_recursive**

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the reply ..   But I want to execute multiple function in a loop ..  as in test.html which actually will be a php file  .. includes many more pages ... so after including everypage I want to show on a div ..page 1 loaded ..page 2 loaded

I hope I made myself clear.

HOpe you can help me up with this :)

thanks
ABHINAB

Comment: you don't need javascript in those ajax pages, just append on ajax success step you accomplished. I'll update my answer in a minute