# AJAX that calls a "parent" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've seen a few questions like the one I'll ask but nothing identical.  I have two html files, main and today.  What I want  to do is load today.html via AJAX into a child div in main.html.  Sometime after load, I would like to call a function that resides in main.html from today.html

Within Main I have this function:

```
function drawCircle (size){             
   alert('DRAWING');
}
```

This AJAX load:

```
$("#leftofad").ajax({
   url: ":Today.html?r="+genRand(),
   type: 'GET',         
   success: function(data) { },
   error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
});
```

And this div:

```
<div id="leftofad"></div>
```

In Today.html I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       
       drawCircle (100);
    });
</script>
```

The load is going well but Today.html doesnt seem to recognize the drawCircle function.  I've tried several precursors including this., window., and parent..

I understand that I can use the callback method of the AJAX loader in jQuery but I don't necessarily want to call drawCircle when the load is complete.  I may want to wait a bit or do it as a result of an action from the user.  Is it possible to reference these functions from an AJAX-loaded div?  If not, can I use an alternative method like events and listeners to fire the drawCircle function?

Comment: What's the content of your success callback? e.g. How are you inserting Today.html into Main.html?

Comment: You didn't put any tags related to .NET in your tag pool, so I dont see why anyone would think it is a .NET question :). Just an observation..

Comment: `$("#leftofad").ajax` isn't a function, it's `$.ajax`, not `$().ajax`.

Comment: When you say "Today.html doesnt seem to recognize the drawCircle function," specifically what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: Today.html is basic html with a  couple of script tags.  I am adding it into a div that I hope will eventually hold many variations of Today.html without reloading main.html.  
When I say Today.html doesnt recognize the function, I mean that a call to drawCircle reutrns:  "Uncaught Reference Error - drawCircle is not defined"

Comment: Are you positive that drawCircle is in the global scope (at least as far as main.html is concerned)? Also what is the significance of the r= query parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you will be loading JS into your page, try **calling the function directly**?
(The ready function won't run as the main page is already loaded)

*Main.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawCircle(size) { alert("DRAWING" + size); }

    $(function() {
        $("#leftofad").load("Today.html?r="+genRand(), function() {
              alert('loaded successfully!');
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="leftofad"></div>
```

*Today.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    drawCircle(100);
</script>
```

If this doesn't work, *I strongly suspect that* JavaScript returned in an AJAX call is not executed.

In this case, refer to: [How to execute javascript inside a script tag returned by an ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978101/how-to-execute-javascript-inside-a-script-tag-returned-by-an-ajax-response)

Answer (score 2):

`$("#leftofad").ajax` is not proper.

jQuery's `$.ajax` function does **not** use a selector.

What you can use is `load`:

```
$("#leftofad").load("Today.html?r="+genRand(), function(){
      alert('loaded successfully!');
});
```

Comment: And even if it was, there is no $(document).ready event after an ajax load into a div.

Comment: I see and understand.  However, switching my .ajax call to .load does not make the functions accessible from Today.html.

Comment: Well, there is a document.ready work-around that works just fine. I created a solution after months of trying ... by accident, it works just like any real html or asp page. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone here has some good answers, but I believe there is a knowledge gap and we are missing some information. If I were you, I would add an alert to the script in the Today.html file right before the drawCirle. Then I would run this page using IE or Chrome dev tools or Firebug in Firefox. When the alert is displayed you can put a breakpoint in the javascript code. Then check your global scope to try and locate drawCirle...

Sorry this is not an exact answer, but with javascript files you need to use debugging tools for this.

Answer (score -1):

while there isn't really a document.ready function for a div, there is a hack that works just as if so:

```
create your returning data as a full html page:
<html>
<head>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready( function () {
   do-this;
   to-that;
    ....
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <% 
   your possible vbscript
 %>
 the rest of stuff to be loaded into that div
</body>
</html>
```

Then, you can have as many cascading div loading from different page loading and .... rinse and repeat ... forever .... EXPERIMENT with different `DOCTYPE` to see the different results.

EDIT:

Then, of course, you load the original MAIN with

```
$('#thedivid').load('url-of-the-html-returning-page');
```

Which, in turn, can have the VERY SAME call in the returning page document.ready as, for example; `$('#thedivid-inthereturningdata-html-page').load('url-of-the-html-of-the-child-process-for-whaterver);` .... and so on.

Go ahead, PLAY AROUND and make wonderful ajax based applications ....