# Javascript doesn't load after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ok the following HTML code is parsed when I load a page:

```
<div id="clip-wrapper"> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        alert("bla");
    </script> 
</div>
```

This obviously leads to an alert saying "bla", after my AJAX call, the parsed HTML code looks like this:

```
<div id="clip-wrapper">
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("ajaxbla");
</script>
</div>
```

This on the other hand, doesn't result in an alert. Why? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there are any scripts loaded into your dom from an Ajax call, they will *not* be executed  for security reasons.

To get the script to execute, you'll need to strip it out of the response, and run it through `eval`

Ideally though, you'll want to run your script as a **callback** for when your ajax request completes.  If you're using jQuery, this would be the **success** event of your ajax call, and if you're doing it natively, it would be the readyStateChange event of your xhr object.

**EDIT**

If you really want to opt for the eval option, you could try something like this:

```
document.getElementById(contentDiv).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
eval(document.getElementById("clip-wrapper").innerHTML);
```

Comment: Can you eleborate how I can get it out of the response? And run it through eval afterwards? I'm using the following code: `function stateChanged() { 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        document.getElementById(contentDiv).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
}`
where contentDiv is clip-wrapper in this case. (is it as simple as eval(xmlHttp.responseText); ?)

Comment: Ok I think I have it right, but it still doesn't work: 
`if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById(contentDiv).innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        eval(document.getElementById(contentDiv).innerHTML);
    }`
am I missing something? Thanks for the help, really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't think eval likes the script tags in there - can you send back the response without them?

Comment: Doesn't that imply that the div will only be filled with 
`alert("msg");` 
so it won't run as javascript code? Or am I understanding you wrongly?

Comment: if it's just filled with alert("msg") you can pass that to eval, and it will definitely work --  eval("alert('msg');"); will work

Comment: for more examples:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978101/how-to-execute-javascript-inside-a-script-tag-returned-by-an-ajax-response

Comment: If you can't attach to the actual ajax call (because it is generated by C# in my case) use $(document).ajaxComplete() and do your work in there.

Answer (score 1):

put you code in

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  alert(msg);
});
```

or make use of readysatchange event of XMLHttp object.

```
XMLHttpobject.readyStateChange( furnction() { alert('msg'); } );
```

**Edit**

if you are using jquery than go for

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

here in sucess event you can write your code which get executed once you are done with the ajax.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, it parses the following HTML code:

    <div id="clip-wrapper"><script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        alert("trolol");
    });
    </script></div>
but it doesn't give an alert. 
PS. how to get code in comments?

Comment: It's included, as I'm using Wordpress.

Comment: I haven't -1'ed you, someone else did. I didn't +1 you either, sorry.

Comment: @peterbond - have you tried ajax call function of edited answer

Comment: No, I haven't, I'm not using jQuery sorry. I +1'ed you (it atleast undid the -1 of someone else) for your effort, as it seems the edited code will work for jQuery, using the success. I've used the solution provided by @Adam Rackis and it works like a charm, also with my real script (loading a movie in jwplayer, depending on what the user clicked on).

Answer (score 1):

any code inside body in between `script` tag will executed only while loading the document.

in ajax call,make use of `callback`  or `success:` or `oncomplete:` to handle the ajax response if you are using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the second html code is coming as an ajax response?? Did you even inserted the html to the current page?

Something like,

```
document.body.innerHTML = ajax_response;
```

But even with `innerHTML` replacement I don't thing the `script` inside it will be auto executed. The browser will parse the `script` but won't auto execute it. (For eg, if you have a `function` definition in the html, after the ajax call you will be able to call those functions)

Another option is to use `document.write`, it will replace the whole page content with the new html and the `script` tags in it will be auto executed.

```
document.write(ajax_response);
```

Hope this helps,