# using AJAX to fetch scripts WITHIN my domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an ajax script which references something in the same domain.  I want to pass some HTML and then javascript associated with it.  I figured that since it is not X-domain, It might let me do that.  My goal is that I am taking a webservice and then returning a string which will be put into a div...  when the javascript is inserted it would be fired, which allows a bunch of good stuff to happen.

I was wondering if there is anything special i need to do to pass javascript from the server across this request.  My current AJAX request seems to sanitize and remove the scripts.  THoughts?  How would i go about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to execute javascript inside a script tag returned by an ajax response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978101/how-to-execute-javascript-inside-a-script-tag-returned-by-an-ajax-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want script to be included in the AJAX response and executed by the browser, you will first need to do something similar to the article posted as a potential duplicate, excepting that you have HTML to be injected as well.  Proceed injecting it as normal, but after you set the content, try something such as:

```
$(responseText).find("script").each(function(index, element){
    var script = $(element).text();
    eval(script); 
}
```

**Untested**

However, I would try to find a way to avoid doing the above.  JQuery provides ways to handle classes of elements added dynamically to the DOM.  See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: is script in your case, a var?   I was not sure if it would be var script = $(element).text();

Comment: From my understanding then, it will evaluate the script before the inserting into the inner HTML.  The script is not something that is like an onload event, so that the javascript would need to be fired AFTER the html insert.   Same method, just move where it is located?

Comment: Yeah - I mean execute it after you insert the HTML.  I think I put before initially, and then changed it ;)  Brain was off.

Comment: It doesnt work from my test, but has opened a door which maybe you can help with.  Instead of your function, I was just going to put the following code segment:  eval($(result.getWebFormDesignFieldContentsResult)[2].text);  Essentially, it uses jQuery to parse the string, and then the 3rd item (denoted by 2).text is the javascript.  As a simple test, i tried to put the javascript as "alert('hi');"  but nothing.  THoughts?

Comment: Correction.  It is working.  I just need to assign the internal javascript correctly. :)  Thanks a lot.