# How to execute the <script> tags loaded from the AJAX request in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I know this question has been asked a lot, but everywhere on the internet the answers are like a decade old and everyone was suggesting to use `eval` which is not a right/secure way to do it.

So, in my AJAX request, as a response, I'm getting some markup including a couple of `<script>` tags, containing the inline scripts and not using `src` attribute. I'm currently using the `.html()` method of jQuery to add the HTML to the DOM, but, in this approach, the **script tags are not executed**.

Suppose, this is the response from the AJAX request:

```
<div>**Random code**</div>
<div>**More random code**</div>
<script type="text/javascript">console.log(1);</script>
<script type="text/javascript">console.log(2);</script>
<div>**More random code**</div>
```

Now, how can I execute the in-between scripts and log to the console:

```
1
2
```

Is there a way to tackle this issue apart from using the `eval` or **script tags with src attribute**? Can we do something with the response received from our AJAX request to execute the particular `<script>` tags?

Comment: In theory you could extract the script tags BEFORE you write to the screen, then just write to the screen the code without the script tags. Then loop through the script tags like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280555/3684265 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/29997435/3684265

Comment: @imvain, I don't think `$.globalEval()` is any better either.

Comment: @LGSon, This question might look duplicate, but currently, there is no answer I can find on the SO, to solve this problem.

Comment: Added this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax to the dupes...it has some interesting tricks.

Comment: And note, there is many things one would like to do in a certain way, though for some one simply can't, and this is one, hence those ancient solution still applies.

Comment: Found this article, that might be useful: https://ghinda.net/article/script-tags/