# Symfony 5 How to display multiple Google Charts with jQuery ui Tabs

Tags: symfony, jquery-ui, symfony5

My first Symfony 5 attempt and I am trying to use Google Charts for the first time. I am using CMENGoogleChartsBundle which provides a Twig extension and PHP objects to display the Charts.

I want to display different Charts which should be accessible through jQuery UI Tabs I also have a table with all the data being displayed. When now clicking on a Tab with a country for example I want the Graph and table updated. I tried to display all the data directly in my twig template (fruitsoverview.html.twig), but when clicking on a tab I would get the page rendered again just below the tabs, plus I would lose any possible set up of my search filter, if the whole page would be re-loaded. I then read that you can create a view just with the content which needs updating so I have done that and in my controller I now have:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
{

return $this->render('fruits/chart.html.twig', [
        'searchFilter' => $searchFilter->createView(),
        'fruitCounts' => $fruitCounts,
        'barchart' => $barchart
        ]);
}else{

    return $this->render('fruits/fruitsoverview.html.twig', [
        'searchFilter' => $searchFilter->createView(),
        'fruitCounts' => $fruitCounts,
        'barchart' => $barchart
        ]);
}}
```

This solved the problem with the rendering, but the chart is not shown. The chart data is available in the twig view but the Graph only gets shown on the default Tab. I do get the table displayed with the correct data. What could be wrong or better question, how is it supposed to be set up correctly. I am sure I have not understood the concept of Symfony yet and probably not of the jQuery ui Tabs. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have now updated my code and got partly working besides the barchart. So the twig variables for the table are updating with the new content after the AJAX request, but the barchart does not change. I have done
{{ dump(barchart) }} in the chart.html.twig and I do get the updated data inside of that as well, but the chart is not re-drawn. How can I achieve that?

**controller**

```
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {         
        $response = new JsonResponse();
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        return new JsonResponse([
                'html' => $this->renderView('fruits/chart.html.twig', [ 
                    'fruitCounts' => $fruitCounts,
                    'barchart' => $barchart
                    ])     
                ]);
```

In my main template I have the below code and Javascript. $("div#client-loop-container").html(data.html); seems to update the twig variables in my chart.twig template.

```
   <div id="client-loop-container">
     {% include 'chart.html.twig' %}
   </div>


     {% block javascripts %}
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}

     <script type="text/javascript">

     $( function() {

     $('#country-tabs a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $(this).tab('show');
        var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href');

        var form = $('form');

        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: loadurl,  
            type:       'POST',
            data: form.serializeArray(),
            dataType:   'json',  

            success: function(data, status) {  

               $("div#client-loop-container").html(data.html);  
            }
          }).responseText;
        });
```

**chart.html.twig**

```
    <div id="client-loop-container">
    <div class="w-100" id="div_chart"></div>

        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                {% for fruitcount in fruitcounts %}
                    <th>{{ fruitcount }} </th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

        {% block javascripts %}

         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          {{ gc_draw(barchart, 'div_chart') }}          
        </script>

       {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why do not rendering all charts and display each one in his Tab without ajax ?

Comment: To be honest, I got pretty lost in all this. Sometimes the Graph pops up then I switch to another tab no Graph click between the tabs they sometimes there sometimes not. Seems to be very randomly. I also just want to know how it should be done correctly so "Best Practice" to achieve this.

Comment: Scripts in an ajax response won't execute automatically just by inserting it in the dom, you'd have to execute it yourself. At that point having a bundle generating the code it's going to be a hinderance more than anything, I'd save yourself the trouble and render all charts at once without using ajax, as suggested before. You can try to adapt [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978101#978171) to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution. The code below uses a single `<div>` for displaying charts but you might be able to adapt to a tab & `id="..."` solution. The approach uses `jQuery.getScript()` to run chart-specific javascript. A ChartService uses the  `cmen/google-charts-bundle` to generate the javascript. The script is supplied to the displaying template by a Controller response. There are six different charts that can be displayed. The page displays charts in pseudo-carousel style.

You might ask why go to all this trouble when it's possible to draw all six charts once and use javascript to hide and show one chart at a time. The answer is that charts 2 - n will usually not have all of its options displayed. I developed this solution so that the vertical axis would always show values at grid lines.

ChartService (with chart definitions eliminated for brevity):

```
namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\RV;
use App\Entity\Summary;
use CMEN\GoogleChartsBundle\GoogleCharts\Options\VAxis;
use CMEN\GoogleChartsBundle\GoogleCharts\Charts\Histogram;
use CMEN\GoogleChartsBundle\GoogleCharts\Charts\LineChart;
use CMEN\GoogleChartsBundle\Twig\GoogleChartsExtension;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class ChartService
{

    private $em;
    private $gce;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, GoogleChartsExtension $gce)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->gce = $gce;
    }

    public function buildChart($chartType, $class, $subtype = null)
    {
        switch ($chartType) {
            case 'line':
                return $this->lineChart($class, $subtype);
                break;
            case 'histogram':
                return $this->histoChart($class);
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private function lineChart($class, $type)
    {
...
        return $chart;
    }

    private function histoChart($class)
    {
...
        return $histo;
    }

    public function getChartJs($chartSpecs, $location)
    {
        $chartType = $chartSpecs['type'] ?? null;
        $class = $chartSpecs['class'] ?? null;
        $subtype = $chartSpecs['subtype'] ?? null;

        $chart = $this->buildChart($chartType, $class, $subtype);

        $js = $this->getStart($chart, $location);
        $end = $this->getEnd($chart, $location);
        $part3 = substr($end, 0, strlen($end) - 1);

        return $js . $end;
    }

    private function getStart($chart, $location)
    {
        return $this->gce->gcStart($chart, $location);
    }

    private function getEnd($chart, $location)
    {
        return $this->gce->gcEnd($chart, $location);
    }

}
```

chartSwitch.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = $('#currentChart').attr('data-chart');
    chartSwitch(i);

    $('#chartNext').on('click', function () {
        i++;
        if (6 === i) {
            i = 0;
        }
        chartSwitch(i);
    });

    $('#chartPrevious').on('click', function () {
        i--;
        if (-1 === i) {
            i = 5;
        }
        chartSwitch(i);
    });

    function chartSwitch(i) {
        $('#currentChart').attr('data-chart', i);
        var url = "/js/" + i;
        $.getScript(url);
    }
});
```

Controller method for `/js/ + i`

```
    /**
     * @Route("/js/{which}", name="js")
     */
    public function returnChartJs(ChartService $chart, $which)
    {
        $available = [
            ['type' => 'line', 'class' => 'C', 'subtype' => 'Price'],
            ['type' => 'line', 'class' => 'C', 'subtype' => 'Count'],
            ['type' => 'line', 'class' => 'B+', 'subtype' => 'Price'],
            ['type' => 'line', 'class' => 'B+', 'subtype' => 'Count'],
            ['type' => 'histogram', 'class' => 'C'],
            ['type' => 'histogram', 'class' => 'B+'],
        ];

        $js = $chart->getChartJs($available[$which], 'chartA');
        $response = new Response($js);

        return $response;
    }
```

Relevant pieces from displaying template:

```
        <div class="col-9 text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3"></div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <span id="currentChart" data-chart="0"></span>
                    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a id="chartPrevious" class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo; Chart</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a id="chartNext" class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">Chart &raquo;</span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>            
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div id="chartA"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
...
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('charts') }}
{% endblock %}
```